# Append HTML into div tag with PHP

Tags: php, html, append

I want to append a variable containing HTML text in php to a preloaded div element in the same file. I am using simpler examples to try and achieve what I want.

```
<?php
    $htmlString = "<p>Hello World!</p>";
?>
```

$htmlString is generated from a PHP function so I just want to put a sample html code to mimic HTML code. Iam trying to put $htmlString in the div element

```
<div id="demo"><h1>Test</h1></div>
```

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
<?php
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $div_tag = $dom->getElementById('demo');
    echo $dom->saveHTML($div_tag);
?>
```

I want to produce this output:

```
<div id="demo"><h1>Test</h1><p>Hello World!</p></div>
```

Comment: If it's just a string you shouldn't use PHP but JS. Otherwise try an AJAX.

Comment: @Oliver My $htmlstring is actually generated from a PHP function

Comment: Okay and if I unserstood right you just want to insert that String in a loaded HTML-Div. But are you running the php-function creating the string when the page is loaded or delayed? If you are doing it delayed you should already have an AJAX-Call

Comment: @Oliver I want to have it created when the page is loaded.

Comment: yes, I just want to insert the string in a HTML-div

Comment: What is `doesn't work`? What is the output?

Comment: @Kimberley see answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call php in between html-tags:

```
<div id="demo"><h1>Test</h1><?php echo $htmlString ?></div>
```

Comment: i'm trying to do this within wordpress and it can't parse php within. so i'm trying to do it from the page editor to parse the html into the div element by id

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.